# How to tie thunderbolt and power together for Macbook retina docking in Thunderbolt display?

Tags: macbook-pro, thunderbolt-display

When docking my Macbook Pro Retina to a Thunderbolt display I need to plug in two cables (a power cable plug, and a thunderbolt cable). I read in a comment that there might be a simple way of clipping the cables together so that they can be plugged into the Macbook in one motion.

- Is there a clip that can be purchased that links the power cable and thunderbolt cable together for individual entry?
- Alternatively, is there some simple do-it-yourself option for keeping the cable together and in the one place?

Answer (score 1):

After a little searching I found a few options

- The [Macbook Pro Dock Cable from Prototype Asia.](http://www.shapeways.com/model/1613864/macbook-pro-dock-cable-thunderbolt-magsafe.html). This looks like a very cheap clipping option. However, the company or individual selling it seems pretty small-scale.
- [ZenDock](http://zenboxx.com/) is a simple docking solution that makes a single left side plug for power and other thuderbolt ports. At time of posting (July 2014), it is only available on pre-order.
- [LandingZone 2.0 Pro](http://landingzone.net/products/pro-2/) provides a docking and security solution that allows for one-click entry of power and thunderbolt.